# How to prevent overlapping of subplots in Plotly using `make_subplots`

Tags: python, python-3.x, plotly-dash, heatmap, plotly-python

I am creating a dashboard to visualize data using the Plotly and Dash packages in Python.

I use the `prepare_plot_data` and `prepare_data_trend` functions to prepare the data for plotting.

I am trying to create two subplots in one figure using `make_subplots` to set up the figure layout. However, the two subplots overlap each other at the same position.

As far as I understand, `make_subplots` allows the position of the subplot to be defined using row and column indices. In my case, I set the rows to 2 and the columns to 1. This should create two positions in the figure: one at (1, 1) and another at (2, 1).

When I plot the first heatmap graph, I set the row to 1 and the column to 1, expecting it to be placed at the (1, 1) position. For the second plot, I set the row to 2 and the column to 1, expecting it to be placed at (2, 1). However, the outcome does not match my expectations based on how I imagine it should look.

Does anyone know how to separate the subplots into different positions? Or do I misunderstand how Plotly's `make_subplots` works?

```
from datetime import date, datetime
from functools import reduce

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from dash import Dash, Input, Output, dcc, html
from loguru import logger
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
from scipy import stats


class OverView:
    def __init__(self):
        self.catologs = ["1","2","3",]

    def prepare_plot_data(self, start_date, end_date):
        data = [
            {"date":"2020-01-01", "1":0.1},
            {"date":"2020-01-01", "2":-0.1},
            {"date":"2020-01-01", "3":0.9},
            {"date":"2020-02-01", "1":0.1},
            {"date":"2020-02-01", "2":0.1},
            {"date":"2020-02-01", "3":0.1},
            {"date":"2020-03-01", "1":0.1},
            {"date":"2020-03-01", "2":0.1},
            {"date":"2020-03-01", "3":0.1},
        ]
        return pd.DataFrame(data)

    def prepare_data_trend(self, start_date, end_date):
        data = [
            {"year-month":"2020-01", "id":"1", "normal_slope":0.1},
            {"year-month":"2020-01", "id":"2", "normal_slope":-0.1},
            {"year-month":"2020-01", "id":"3", "normal_slope":0.9},
            {"year-month":"2020-02", "id":"1", "normal_slope":0.12},
            {"year-month":"2020-02", "id":"2", "normal_slope":0.15},
            {"year-month":"2020-02", "id":"3", "normal_slope":-0.15},
            {"year-month":"2020-03", "id":"1", "normal_slope":0.5},
            {"year-month":"2020-03", "id":"2", "normal_slope":0.3},
            {"year-month":"2020-03", "id":"3", "normal_slope":0.2},
        ]
        return pd.DataFrame(data)

    def plot(self, start_date=None, end_date=None):
        df = self.prepare_plot_data(start_date, end_date)
        df_trend = self.prepare_data_trend(start_date, end_date)

        fig = make_subplots(
            rows=2, cols=1, row_heights=[0.6, 0.4],
            specs=[
                [{"type": "xy", "colspan": 1, "rowspan": 1}],
                [{"type": "xy", "colspan": 1,  "rowspan": 1, "secondary_y": True}],

            ],
            horizontal_spacing=0,
            vertical_spacing=0.01,
        )

        fig1 = go.Heatmap(
            x=df_trend['year-month'].tolist(),
            y=df_trend['id'].tolist(),
            z=df_trend['normal_slope'].tolist(),
            colorbar=dict(title='heat'),
        )
        fig.add_trace(fig1, row=1, col=1,)
        fig.update_traces(colorbar_orientation='h', selector=dict(type='heatmap'))

        for catolog in self.catologs:
            fig.add_trace(
                go.Scatter(
                    x=df["date"].values,
                    y=df[catolog].values,
                    name=catolog,
                ),
                secondary_y=True,
                row=2, col=1,
            )
        return fig

    def run_dash(self):
        app = Dash(__name__)
        app.layout = html.Div(
            [
                html.H1("tmp Overview"),
                dcc.DatePickerRange(
                    id="my-date-picker-range",
                    min_date_allowed=date(1990, 1, 1),
                    max_date_allowed=date(2100, 12, 31),
                    initial_visible_month=date(2021, 1, 1),
                    start_date=date(2018, 1, 1),
                    end_date=date(2023, 12, 31),
                ),
                dcc.Graph(id="graph"),
            ],
        )

        @app.callback(
            Output("graph", "figure"),
            [
                Input("my-date-picker-range", "start_date"),
                Input("my-date-picker-range", "end_date"),
            ],
        )
        def update_output(start_date, end_date):
            return self.plot(start_date, end_date)
        app.run_server(debug=True)


OverView().run_dash()
```

the result is as below
[image]

the correct result should have two graphs as the below
[image]
[image]

Comment: FYI I had added a solution if you are still interested in one for this question

Answer (score 0):

You are correct in your understanding of the `make_subplots` function and its axes indices! The problem seems to be with the custom adjustments you made to the horizontal and vertical placement aspects. Approaching this with a simplified declaration of `make_subplots` seems to solve the issue:

```py
from datetime import date, datetime
from functools import reduce

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from dash import Dash, Input, Output, dcc, html
from loguru import logger
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
from scipy import stats


class OverView:
    def __init__(self):
        self.catologs = [
            "1",
            "2",
            "3",
        ]

    def prepare_plot_data(self, start_date, end_date):
        data = [
            {"date": "2020-01-01", "1": 0.1},
            {"date": "2020-01-01", "2": -0.1},
            {"date": "2020-01-01", "3": 0.9},
            {"date": "2020-02-01", "1": 0.1},
            {"date": "2020-02-01", "2": 0.1},
            {"date": "2020-02-01", "3": 0.1},
            {"date": "2020-03-01", "1": 0.1},
            {"date": "2020-03-01", "2": 0.1},
            {"date": "2020-03-01", "3": 0.1},
        ]
        return pd.DataFrame(data)

    def prepare_data_trend(self, start_date, end_date):
        data = [
            {"year-month": "2020-01", "id": "1", "normal_slope": 0.1},
            {"year-month": "2020-01", "id": "2", "normal_slope": -0.1},
            {"year-month": "2020-01", "id": "3", "normal_slope": 0.9},
            {"year-month": "2020-02", "id": "1", "normal_slope": 0.12},
            {"year-month": "2020-02", "id": "2", "normal_slope": 0.15},
            {"year-month": "2020-02", "id": "3", "normal_slope": -0.15},
            {"year-month": "2020-03", "id": "1", "normal_slope": 0.5},
            {"year-month": "2020-03", "id": "2", "normal_slope": 0.3},
            {"year-month": "2020-03", "id": "3", "normal_slope": 0.2},
        ]
        return pd.DataFrame(data)

    def plot(self, start_date=None, end_date=None):
        df = self.prepare_plot_data(start_date, end_date)
        df_trend = self.prepare_data_trend(start_date, end_date)

        fig = make_subplots(rows=2)

        fig1 = go.Heatmap(
            x=df_trend["year-month"].tolist(),
            y=df_trend["id"].tolist(),
            z=df_trend["normal_slope"].tolist(),
            colorbar=dict(title="heat"),
        )
        fig.add_trace(
            fig1, row=1, col=1,
        )
        fig.update_traces(
            colorbar_orientation="h", selector=dict(type="heatmap")
        )

        for catolog in self.catologs:
            fig.add_trace(
                go.Scatter(
                    x=df["date"].values, y=df[catolog].values, name=catolog,
                ),
                row=2,
                col=1,
            )
        return fig

    def run_dash(self):
        app = Dash(__name__)
        app.layout = html.Div(
            [
                html.H1("tmp Overview"),
                dcc.DatePickerRange(
                    id="my-date-picker-range",
                    min_date_allowed=date(1990, 1, 1),
                    max_date_allowed=date(2100, 12, 31),
                    initial_visible_month=date(2021, 1, 1),
                    start_date=date(2018, 1, 1),
                    end_date=date(2023, 12, 31),
                ),
                dcc.Graph(id="graph"),
            ],
        )

        @app.callback(
            Output("graph", "figure"),
            [
                Input("my-date-picker-range", "start_date"),
                Input("my-date-picker-range", "end_date"),
            ],
        )
        def update_output(start_date, end_date):
            return self.plot(start_date, end_date)

        app.run_server(debug=True)


OverView().run_dash()
```

gives:
[image: Screenshot of resulting Dash app showing properly displayed Plotly subplots]